# Tracking Event Google Analytics

Tags: javascript, google, google-analytics-api

Olá tenho um slider dentro do site e gostaria de criar uma tracking event dentro deste slider. Dentro deste slider possui 6 imagens, então tipo até qual imagem o usuário foi, qual é a mais visualizada e cia. alguem pode me ajudar?

Answer (score 1):

Não sei qual plugin de slider você está usando, mas é muito comum que esses plugins já tenham opções para lidar com callbacks. Algo como:

```
$(function() {
      $('#slides').slidesjs({
        width: 940,
        height: 528,
        callback: {
          complete: function(number) {
            console.log('O slide mostrado é o número ' + number);
          }
        }
      });
    });
```

Você pode usar esse callback para mandar um evento para o GA toda vez que a transição for completada.

```
callback: {
          complete: function(number) {
            ga('send', 'event', 'home', 'impressao', 'slider', number);
          }
        }
```

Assim você consegue saber qual imagem teve mais impressões usando o `number` como identificador ou até mesmo atribuindo o nome da imagem ao label do evento.